# In MVVM why people are creating a ViewModel folder?

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm

... intead of using the xxx.xaml.cs generated file?

Developer are creating a View in xaml in the Views folder. Visual Studio generate the xaml.cs file just under the xaml file. But developer prefer creating a new folder ViewModel and for each xxx xaml file they create a xxxViewModel.cs file. Why don't move all the content of these ViewModels in the xxx.xaml.cs file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people even like to nest the ViewModel directly under the `xaml` file, like
[image]

This can be done by using this custom Visual Studio extension: [NestIn](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9d6ef0ce-2bef-4a82-9a84-7718caa5bb45/)

Comment: I like the answer They are creating folders because key MVVM examples (by Josh Smith and Laurent Bugnion) show this approach. Thank you for this extension. I'm happy to know I'm not alone to prefer nested files.

Comment: In the end I think it's a matter of preferences, but given the fact that there should always be a 1-1 mapping between view and viewmodel, this approach looks intuitive to me and it is why I think I'll try it out in my next project. 
If u're interested, I found it here: http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2010/11/07/in-the-box-ndash-mvvm-training/ with some additional MVVM training material which looks quite interesting to go through.

Answer (score 3):

Because the xaml.cs it tightly coupled to the xaml (view), which goes against the pattern design.

Please have a look at this link, which explains the pattern nicely : http://reedcopsey.com/2010/01/06/better-user-and-developer-experiences-from-windows-forms-to-wpf-with-mvvm-part-7-mvvm/ :

> The ViewModel
>
> - The ViewModel knows nothing about the View
> - The ViewModel directly interacts with the Model, in order to expose it for data binding
> - The ViewModel manages the Application-specific information

Comment: Point 1 is not always taken so strictly.

Comment: Point 1 is the only one that explain why developers are creating the ViewModel in another structure/namespace than the genarated xxx.xaml.cs file. My next question is why the ViewModel should know nothing about the View?

Comment: @DranDane - the link points you to an excellent series of articles about MVVM. You should start reading.

Answer (score 1):

This split provides clear [seperation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) between presentation logic (how user interfaces behave) and rendering (how user interface look). It puts all logic into a layer where it can be [unit tested](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing), and puts all markup in a layer where a graphic designer can work without fear of breaking things too easily.

Answer (score 0):

They are creating folders because key MVVM examples (by Josh Smith and Laurent Bugnion) show this approach.

> Why don't move all the content of these ViewModels in the xxx.xaml.cs file?

Because it's wrong. xxx.xaml.cs is a "code-behind", it's a part of the UI. The idea of MVVM is to separate UI from the view model. UI should not be aware of any details of the logic it displays.

Comment: ViewModel is also a part of the UI. If I change my UI I'll have to change my ViewModel. All documentation I read about ViewModel set the ViewModel in the UI part. What is the difference between using xxx.xaml.cs is a "code-behind" or ViewModel folder/namespace? I must refer my ViewModel namespace in my xxx.xaml.cs so what? It's the same!

Comment: 1) You can use different Views with a single VM.
2) Not every change of UI means changes in VM. Thus, separating them in different files is convenient. Just as it always is with different classes in different files.

Comment: 3) And don't think about VM as a part of UI. It is not. It is a logic that UI displays.

Comment: I don't see the reason to have a ViewModel without the specific View that is linked to it. It's not the Model? If it's not a part of the UI what is it?

Answer (score -1):

Because it is easier to test the classes with Unit tests. Nothing is bound to the view then.