# MVVM: why the ViewModel should know nothing about the View?

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm

After asking this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11557539/196526) i get answers that call new questions

1. Why UI should not be aware of any details of the logic it displays?
2. Why the ViewModel should know nothing about the View?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To be reusable regardless of the context it's used in.
2. Look point 1.

Comment: And the most important "re-use" is during unit tests. Without the pesky view to get in the way, the view's logic (view model) can be tested as you would any other part of the application. In a non-structured UI (where you bake the code straight into the form), it'd be tangled with view-specific code that you'd have to battle against in tests.

Answer (score 1):

One word to answer your 2 problems: Tight-coupling. Further explanation includes separation of concerns and prevention of bad coding habits which may lead to security issues.

Sux, why is this not considered ?

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have said this maintains loose coupling between the ViewModel and the View, but it also adhere's to the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).  Should the ViewModel care how it's data is being displayed to the user?  This is the responsibility of the View only.

All classes should have 1, and only 1, reason to change.  Having logic in the View means that you break this rule, you need to change it if the logic changes where you should only change it if the UI needs a change.

Answer (score 0):

the viewmodel contains the view logic - thats what you wanna unittest. 
The View is just a pretty interface that allows users to interact with your ViewModels.

> Why the ViewModel should know nothing about the View?

the viewmodel should **not have a reference** to the view.

Comment: pls comment your downvote - it does not help anyone otherwise